# Form fields are empty on serialize when processed thru JavaScript Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, es6-modules, es6-class

I hope my question is somehow understandable, I have a ES6 Class which gets initialized on a regular Form which then gets processed via ajax call (not included in the example).

When I try to serialize the formData it returns empty instead of the value of the first_name input. Other actions on the Form as adding or removing classes etc. work fine, just the form won't return any data. I assume I'm somehow lost my $.this in scope. I'm new trying to build my JavaScript in Modules and Classes and abstract coding. The Form works as expected when I call and process it with regular jQuery ready code but just can't figure out where the problem is here.

script.js

```
import $ from 'jquery'

class CustomSubmit extends window.HTMLElement {
  constructor (...args) {
    const self = super(...args)
    self.init()
    return self
  }

  init () {
    this.$ = $(this)
    this.resolveElements()
    this.bindFunctions()
    this.bindEvents()
  }

  resolveElements () {
    // Get the Form
    this.$bidForm = $( '#CustomSubmitForm' , this)
  }

  bindFunctions () {
      this.sendForm = this.sendForm.bind(this)
  }

  bindEvents () {
    // Attach sendForm function to Form Submit  
    this.$.submit('[data-form-submit]', this.sendForm)
  }

  sendForm (e) {

    e.preventDefault()
    const formData = this.$.serialize()
    // here is the problem, formData is empty
    console.log(formData)

  }
}

window.customElements.define('submit-form', CustomSubmit, { extends: 'form' })
```

form.html

```
<form is="submit-form" id="CustomSubmitForm">
<input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name">
<button type="submit" [data-form-submit] >Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `this.$bidForm = $( '#CustomSubmitForm' , this)` doesn't make sense to me. Doesn't that select only descndants?

Comment: You are right, wasn't the problem thou, but still worked on other code I had. Thanks for pointing it out ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're using

```
class CustomSubmit extends window.HTMLElement {
```

but an ordinary `HTMLElement` doesn't have [any `<form>`-specific properties and methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement) that would allow jQuery to collect values from all elements. Instead, use

```
class CustomSubmit extends window.HTMLFormElement {
//                                    ^^^^
```

Comment:  OMG thanks so much! Solved the problem and now works as expected! Thank you so much!